# JSON response error in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter framework and json. I want to fetch data from the database when the user clicks on a url, but I'm getting an error.

My script:

```
function abc(i)
{
   if(i == 1)
   {
     $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: "<?php echo base_url('welcome/liststd');?>",
       data: 'postData='+ i ,
       success: function(json)
       {
         var abc = json;
         document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML=abc[0].fname; 
       }
    });
  }
 }
```

Firebug Response:

```
[
   {
     "id":"31",
     "fname":"Darshan",
      "mname":"D",
      "lname":"Dave",
      "std":"1",
      "marks":"12000",
      "image":"image31.jpg",
      "id1":"1",
      "in_date":"0000-00-00",
      "upd_date":"2013-07-10"
   },
   {
      "id":"34",
      "fname":"Darshan",
      "mname":"D",
      "lname":"Dave",
      "std":"1",
      "marks":"12000",
      "image":"image34.jpg",
      "id1":"1",
      "in_date":"2013-07-06",
      "upd_date":"2013-07-09"
     }
   ]
```

When I alert `json` in the `success` function it shows me this:

```
[
   {
     "id":"31",
     "fname":"Darshan",
      "mname":"D",
      "lname":"Dave",
      "std":"1",
      "marks":"12000",
      "image":"image31.jpg",
      "id1":"1",
      "in_date":"0000-00-00",
      "upd_date":"2013-07-10"
   },
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Very well-asked question. Specifics, code, some debugging you've already done, great stuff. One small thing for future questions: Instead of "I got some error" say **what**, exactly, the error is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder okey thnx for your reply...:)

Answer (score 3):

You aren't parsing the JSON. Add `dataType : 'json'` to the ajax call. This will tell jQuery to automatically parse the JSON for you.

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "post",
     url: "<?php echo base_url('welcome/liststd');?>",
     data: 'postData=' + i,
     dataType: 'json', // <----- tell jQuery to parse the JSON
     success: function (json) {
         var abc = json;
         document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML = abc[0].fname;
     }
 });
```

Comment: *"Add `dataType : 'json'` to the ajax call"* Or better yet, have the server return the correct `Content-Type`.

Comment: @MrCode when i alert json why i got only 0th element only?

Comment: By targeting `abc[0].fname` you are always reading the first. You can use a loop if you want to iterate over them all.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this in your response...
also in your $.ajax tell jquery to parse json
 dataType: 'json'
in your response..
var response = JSON.parse(json);
response.fname;
```

Comment: This is just a duplicate of the answer that was here 10 minutes earlier. Also, please refer to the **How to Format** box next to the editing area when you were typing, and the preview area underneath where you could see what your answer would look like.